# Why is {} < function(){}?

Tags: javascript, operators, logical-operators

While I was messing around with truth tables in JavaScript, I noticed that the following evaluates to true:

```
var a, b, c;
a = {};
b = function(){};
c = a < b;
console.log(c);
```

Why?

<sub>I've only tested this in Firefox, and I'm sure I could dig up the details in the ECMAScript 2.6.2 spec, but TBH I'm feeling lazy.</sub>

Comment: It's true in Chrome too.

Comment: Looks like it might just be comparing addresses of the objects. If you can reason confidently about the nature of the entities `a` and `b`, then you probably won't find this scary... though I certainly can't :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JavaScript type coercion makes the comparison essentially

```
String({}) < String(function(){})
```

so essentially you are just doing

```
"[object Object]" < "function (){}"
```

which is a lexicographic string comparison.

Comment: See [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), section 11.8.5

Comment: Or [this 11.8.5](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5) if you don't want to wade through a PDF.

Answer (score 8):

Javascript [compares objects](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.8) by calling `valueOf()` or `toString()`.
Since neither operand has a `valueOf()` method, it will compare the `toString()`s.

`({}).toString()` is `[object Object]`.
`(function() { }).toString()` is `function() { }`.

`[` is less than `f`.

Answer (score 4):

```
alert(({}))            -> [object Object]
alert((function(){}))  -> function () {}
```

`[` comes before `f`, hence `({}) < (function () {})`.

Yes, it's silly. ;)

Answer (score 0):

pretty simple and easy ( **internally  they are both converted to strings** ) this is because in Javascript

If an object is compared with a number or string, JavaScript attempts to return the default value for the object. Operators attempt to convert the object to a primitive value, a String or Number value, using the valueOf and toString methods of the objects.

so when both are compared both objects are converted to string using the internal Tostring method

```
    a.toString()
"[object Object]"

b.toString()
"function () { }"
```

hence b will be greater than a  ( larger string ) 
that's why b > a  is true