# A function is larger than an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, comparison, ecmascript-5

A friend of mine discovered some interesting behaviour in some Javascript code, which I decided to investigate further.

The comparison

```
(function (x) {return x*x;}) > [1,2,3]
```

returns `true` in most major browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari) and `false` in IE9. To me, there is no logical result of this comparison other than `undefined` as there is no way to say that a function is greater than an array.

Reading up on this in the ECMA-script standard, it says that the actual arguments of `>` when it is used on objects are the result of calling the ToNumber internal operation on the arguments. Some experiments and further reading tells me that this is not the same as applying a type conversion such as `(Number) arg`. Reading the specification, I have a hard time figuring out what's going on here.

Can anyone fill me in on what's really happening here?

Comment: of course function is larger than array, it can produce heckuvalotta arrays ;-)

Comment: You haven't read enough of the spec yet.  The `>` operator can also compare strings.

Comment: @Pointy, indeed. 'f' is greater than '1' (is there a hidden meaning?).

Comment: Hint: try `(function() {}) > [ "zebra", "giraffe" ]`

Comment: Note `x*x` is `Math.pow(x,2)`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116407/why-is-function

Comment: function is smaller than zerba with giraffe. Understandable.

Comment: I guess there actually is the logic. I might be wrong, but in this example the code you've wrote is equivalent to `'function (x) {return x*x;}' > 'Array'`, so it compares strings length, I believe. Try to alert both sides. I don't know, but may be in IE such access is restricted?

Comment: @Yuri no it compares them as strings, not by string length. And an array becomes a string by a call to `.join()`.

Comment: Was the orginal comparison accidental?  I can't really picture a scenario which would lead to writing that code intentionally...

Comment: @AShelly: A friend is writing a compiler from Haskell to Javascript as his master's thesis in computer science and stumbled upon this in his generated code. I just got intrigued by this and had to investigate further.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The operands to `>` are not necessarily converted to numbers. The [abstract relational comparison algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5) calls `ToPrimitive` with the *hint* `Number`, but `ToPrimitive` may still return a string (and in the case of both functions and arrays, it does).

So you end up comparing two strings. The result of calling [`toString` on function objects](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.2) is not defined by the spec, although most major engines return the source code of the function (or some form of it, and the formatting varies). The result of calling [`toString` on arrays](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.2) is the same as [`join`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.5).

So the odds are that you'll end up basically doing this:

```
"function (x) {return x*x;}" > "1,2,3"
```

Since the exact form of the string for the function may vary from browser-to-browser (and note [Esailija's investigations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9381506/157247) — looks like IE9 keeps the outer `()`, Chrome doesn't), it's not too surprising that the result may vary.

Comment: Could also be 'function(){...' and '1,2,3' (I think that's what Chrome will make of those).

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, and `toString` on functions returns the source (usually, not guaranteed). I was thinking of `Object.prototype.toString.call(func)` -- doh!

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! I think I hurried too much while reading through the spec.
That aside, this is a horrible way to deal with comparisons.

Comment: @evilcandybag: Have a read through the algorithm and the various operations it triggers, there *is* a method to the (seeming) madness. I have to admit I'd kind of like to have the option of using a "strict relational comparison" operator (like we have strict equality/inequality operators, `===` and `!==`), though. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yeah, read through it before I checked your answer as correct. Sure, there is a method to it all. It just seems to me that the language designers want to give a faux sense of flexibility by pretending to do something useful. Then again, I'm no fan of weak typing overall. =P

Comment: @evilcandybag: Ah, that explains it. :-) And yeah, it results in some pretty bizarre behavior.

Answer (score 60):

In IE<9, `.toString`ing `(function (x) {return x*x;})` gives

```
"(function (x) {return x*x;})"
```

While in chrome it gives:

```
"function (x) {return x*x;}"
```

If you compare:

```
"function (x) {return x*x;}" > "1,2,3" // true
"(function (x) {return x*x;})"  > "1,2,3"  // false
```

Which is effectively the same as comparing:

```
"f" > "1"
"(" > "1"
```

Which is the same as comparing:

```
102 > 49
40 > 49
```

So that's how we get from a function and array comparison to a simple number comparison :)

Comment: Interesting analysis of obvious incompatibility, allowed by the spec.

Comment: Not in my IE9: http://i.imgur.com/1zhLa.png.  I only see the parens in IE8/IE7 mode.  Is your browser in compatibility mode?

Comment: @gilly3 true I had IE7 mode, the OP must have had the same mistake as it returns true for the comparison (same as the modern browsers)

Answer (score 5):

Let's dive into the ECMA Specification. I've included the section numbers so you can reference.

**11.8.2 The Greater-than Operator ( > )**

> The production RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression >
>   ShiftExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating RelationalExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref) .
> 5. Let r be the result of performing **abstract relational comparison** rval < lval with LeftFirst equal to false. (see 
>      11.8.5).

The important part of that is the *Abstract Relational Comparison*. Which is defined:

**11.8.5 The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm**

The `toPrimitive` function will first be called on the Objects. Although this is biased to return Numbers if it can, Strings can also be derived. Once this has occurred, the following will be examined:

> a. If py is a prefix of px, return false. (A String value p is a prefix of String value q if q can be the
>   result of concatenating p and some other String r. Note that any
>   String is a prefix of itself, because r may be the empty String.)
>
> b. If px is a prefix of py, return true.
>
> c. Let k be the smallest nonnegative integer **such that the character at position  k within px is different from the character at position k within py**. (There must be such a k, for neither String is a prefix of  the other.)
>
> d. Let m be the integer that is the code unit value for the character at position  k within px. e. Let n be the integer that is the code unit value for the character at position  k within py. f. If m < n, return true. Otherwise, return false.

This means that the first character in the String that is different than the other will be examined. As it has been pointed out by Esailija, IE's `toString()` function returns a slightly different String to that of the other browsers, resulting in a different comparison taking place.

This difference between the browsers appears to be valid as is stated here:

**15.2.4.4 Object.prototype.valueOf ( )**

> When the valueOf method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.
> 2. If O is the result of calling the Object constructor with a host object (15.2.2.1), then a. Return either O or another value such as
>      the host object originally passed to the constructor. The  specific
>      result that is returned is implementation-defined.
> 3. Return O.

Answer (score 2):

Both IE and other browsers will use the same string comparison for both objects.  The reason for the difference is IE will convert the function into the literal string as entered:

```
(function (x) {return x*x;})
```

Other browsers (testing on Firefox) will output its own compiled interpretation of the function:

```
function (x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

Since the first character of IE's function representation is `(`, which is higher than `1`, it will return false.  Since `f` is lower then `1`, other browsers will return true.